# Show that The integral is $(\Bbb E[X_i^2-\tfrac13])^2=0$

Tags: analysis

Show that The integral is $(\Bbb E[X_i^2-\tfrac13])^2=0$

Why does this hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by a direct computation. For $i\neq j$ \begin{align*}
\int_{(0,1)^n} \bigg (x_i^2-\frac 1 3 \bigg ) \bigg (x_j^2-\frac 1 3 \bigg )dx &= \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 \bigg (x_i^2-\frac 1 3 \bigg ) \bigg (x_j^2-\frac 1 3 \bigg ) dx_1 \cdots dx_n \\
&= \bigg ( \int_0^1 \bigg ( t^2 - \frac 1 3 \bigg) d t \bigg )^2 \\
&= 0. 
\end{align*} As an aside we can also compute the case $i = j$: \begin{align*}
\int_{(0,1)^n} \bigg (x_i^2-\frac 1 3 \bigg ) \bigg (x_j^2-\frac 1 3 \bigg ) &= \int_{(0,1)^n} \bigg (x_i^2-\frac 1 3 \bigg )^2 dx_i \\&= \frac 4 {45}. 
\end{align*}

Comment: What did you do on the second line? Where did the $t$ come from?

Comment: Firstly, I used that $$ \int_{(0,1)^n} \prod_{k=1}^n f_k (x_k) d x = \prod_{k=1}^n \int_0^1 f_k (x_k) d x_k$$ which is just a product of 1-dimensional integrals and I used that $\int_0^1 d x_k = 1$. Hence, your integral is equal to $\int_0^1 (x_i^2 - 1/3) dx_i \cdot \int_0^1 (x_j^2 - 1/3) dx_j$. Finally, I $x_i$ and $x_j$ are just dummy variables, so I replaced them with $t$.

Comment: You can replace them with $t$ even though you assumed $x_i \neq x_j$?

Comment: I've assumed $i \neq j$ not $x_i \neq x_j$, but that's not the reason I can replace both $x_i$ and $x_j$ with $t$. Look at each integral independently: they are just the same integral. By replacing $x_i$ with $t$  $\int_0^1 (x_i^2 - 1/3) dx_i = \int_0^1 (t^2 -1/3) d t$. Similarly, replacing $x_j$ with $t$ $\int_0^1 (x_j^2 - 1/3) dx_j = \int_0^1 (t^2 -1/3) d t$.

Answer (score 0):

The integral is $(\Bbb E[X_i^2-\tfrac13])^2=0$, since famously $X_i\sim U(0,\,1)\implies\Bbb E[X_i^2]=\tfrac13$.